# "Unable to find an initial ram disk that I know how to handle" when trying to install new kernel

Tags: debian, linux-kernel

I am trying to install a new kernel that I just built from source using the following command on a machine currently running `Linux rc70 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u2 (2016-01-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux`:

```
sudo dpkg -i ../linux-image-3.16.7+_3.16.7+-10.00.Custom_amd64.deb
```

I get the following error.

```
: Unable to find an initial ram disk that I know how to handle.
Will not try to make an initrd.
```

What causes this error and what steps can I take to try to resolve this error?

Comment: Have you tried to boot with out of it? Strictly speaking you do not need initrd/initramfs if your kernel knows how to mount root partition (i.e it has drivers for your controller (*ata) and filesystem (ext3,4) and ds is not encrypted and no LVM or software raid is used)

Comment: @user996142, It boots fine but the question still stands. :)

Answer (score 5):

This is not an error.

You built a Debian package for the kernel. As part of installing that kernel, the kernel package framework will try to build an initramfs so that you can boot your kernel if you need that.

If you built a custom kernel with no support for initramfs, then this won't work. the `update-initramfs` tool which is ran as part of the installation of that kernel will fail with that message. Since you don't need that initramfs, that's fine. The diagnostic is there in case you *were* expecting an initramfs to be built and it doesn't appear; the message should you get started for debugging what went wrong in that case, but if you don't need or want an initramfs, you can safely ignore it.

If you really really *really* don't want to have an initramfs, you can optionally also remove the `initramfs-tools` package, which contains the `update-initramfs` binary. I wouldn't recommend that, however.